# Angular element replaceWith vs "ng-if"

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm studying  an app with a lot of directives using following code:

```
scope : {
..
  flag: '@'
},
link: function(scope, element){
var template = (scope.flag === 'true') ? 'oneTemplate.html' : 'anotherTemplate.html';

$http.get(template, {cache: $templateCache})
                    .success(function(tplContent){
                        element.replaceWith($compile(tplContent)(scope));
                    }).error(function(e){
                       ...
                    });
}
```

does it have any advantages over having normal directive with single template specified in templateUrl and then ng-if="flag" inside (possibly with ng-include if the htmls are really big)?

The latter seems to be a more straightforward to me.

Comment: This directive is probably meant to eliminate a lot of boilerplate code whenever they want to conditionally load templates.

Comment: yes, but can't same be acheived with ng-if? Seems even less boilerplate code...

Comment: isn't tplContent computed dynamically ?

Comment: it's downloaded, but content is always the same